# I have Bevel Issues

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, edges, bevel

I have this model

[image]

when Enter Edit mode and make bevel to outer face some of vertices have issues

[image]

Here is closer images

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe try to cut some additional edges in the center of the face with the Knife tool?

Comment: I need less edges or vertices when I remove the vertices that make the problem it works fine but shape become not as I want and there is a lot of vertices that  have the same issue it is hard to remove them all

Comment: maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/d69db62d560f495cb6d68606a552b38b

Answer (score 1):

You can cut through some edges with the knife (K to activate, Z to cut through), then bevel but you won't avoid all the overlappings considering your topology, so you'll need to rework a bit. When you're good, just symmetrize on Y:

[image]

You could also select the face ring all around, extrude along normals with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>, then scale on Y, and add some edge loops if necessary to round your bevel. This operation will fatten the shape though, so you can shrink before the operation if you want, with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>:

[image]

[image]

A way to simplify your topology in order to avoid overlapping as much as possible and rework easily would be to delete some edges, to do this you can try a <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*, ot use *Ring Select*, *Checker Deselect* and *Dissolve Edges*, but you'll loose details:

[image]

Comment: your solution is good . . I also found another solution which is something like Dissolve edges , the solution is to Select all vertices then from Mesh menu > Merge By Distance
it will remove some edges and may affect the shape but it will give some space for edges to make bevel without overlapping

Comment: yes it all depends on if you want to keep the shape as it is or if you can sacrifice some vertices, I don't know if there's any easy solution to fix your problem anyway

Comment: you can also try a X > Limited Dissolve which will allow you to dissolve vertices under the angle you'll set, but you'll still need to work